# hg convert doesn't recognise trunk/tags/branches from svn repository

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert

I have tried to convert an SVN project to Mercurial using `svnsync` and then:

```
mercurial-2.2.2/hg convert --authors ../authors.txt project
```

as described [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) (the version of Mercurial supplied by Ubuntu crashed when trying to convert the repository, so I deleted the output and downloaded the latest version of Mercurial instead).

However, the resulting repository has

```
project/trunk/blah
```

and

```
project/tags/1.1/blah
```

as files in the revisions, instead of recognising the trunk as the `default` branch, and the tags as tags.

What is the right way to convert it?

Please note: The project was originally stored something like this in SVN (due to developer error):

```
project/project/trunk
```

but in recent SVN revisions it is like this:

```
project/trunk
```

I assumed that `hg convert` would look at the file structure in HEAD and deduce the correct structure, but obviously I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the command line:

```
--config convert.svn.trunk=project/trunk --config convert.svn.branches=project/branches --config convert.svn.tags=project/tags
```